# Split List based on some value in Python?

Tags: python

I have 3 lists,

```
a = ['Good', '24.97 %']
b = ['Bad', '75.03 %']
c = [('Amount', 0.20),
     ('Decision1', -0.149),
     ('Unit', 0.128),
     ('Decision2', -0.120),
     ('Decision3', 0.038),
     ('Matches', 0.016)]
```

Good corresponds to negative values in list c, bad corresponds to positive values, so I have to separate that in to a new list like

```
Good = ['Good', '24.97 %', ('Decision1', -0.149), ('Decision2', -0.120)]

Bad = ['Bad', '75.03 %', ('Amount', 0.20),('Unit', 0.128),('Decision3', 0.038),
     ('Matches', 0.016)]
```

Comment: Are the name and percentage in a and b related to anything? Why do you include them in the result - they make your list heterogeneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list-comprehension to fetch negatives and positives and append them to other list:

```
good = a + [x for x in c if x[1] < 0]
bad = b + [x for x in c if x[1] > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to get your result:-

```
a = ['Good', '24.97 %']
b = ['Bad', '75.03 %']
c = [('Amount', 0.20),
 ('Decision1', -0.149),
 ('Unit', 0.128),
 ('Decision2', -0.120),
 ('Decision3', 0.038),
 ('Matches', 0.016)]

good = a.copy()
bad = b.copy()
for var in c:
    if var[1] < 0:
        good.append(var)
    else:
        bad.append(var)
print(good)
print(bad)
```

**Output**

```
['Good', '24.97 %', ('Decision1', -0.149), ('Decision2', -0.12)]
['Bad', '75.03 %', ('Amount', 0.2), ('Unit', 0.128), ('Decision3', 0.038), ('Matches', 0.016)]
```

I hope it may help you.